# Solving $y'=2y+3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling because I am dealing with a differential equation that leaves me a bit confused:

$y'=2y+3$

**My attempt to solution**

As $y=\frac{dy}{dx}$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}=2y+3$ so

$$\int {dy}-2\int{y\;dy} = 3\int{dx} \Rightarrow y-\not{2}\frac{y^2}{\not{2}} = 3x+c$$

I feel this isn't the right way to move forward, because there's no chance for me to get the $y$ value so I feel a bit stuck, how do I solve this equation? Every tip, suggestion, comment, remark in the right direction is very welcome.

Comment: The problem is the middle term is $-2\int y\,\mathrm{d}x$, not $dy$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y'=2y+3\iff \frac{dy}{2y+3}=dx$$
Now integrate

Comment: Ok so I get $\int{\frac{dy}{2y+3}=\int{dx}} \Rightarrow 2\log(2y+3)=x \Rightarrow \log(2y+3) = \frac{1}{2}x \Rightarrow e^{\log(2y+3)} = e^{\frac{1}{2}x} \Rightarrow 2y+3 = e^{\frac{1}{2}x} \Rightarrow y = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}x}-3}{2}$. Am I correct? 'Cause I am not so sure.

Comment: Yeah you are right. A good way to check with differentials is just to put your answer back into the original equation. See if when you differentiate $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}x}-3}{2}$ you get $2*[\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}x}-3}{2}] +3$ that is check that your $y' = 2y +3$

Comment: @Mary: Not exactly: first, you need to add a constant to one of the sides. Second, $\int\frac{dy}{2y+3}=\frac12\ln(2y+3)+C$

Comment: @DennisGulko ahhh the pesky constant of integration. Many a mark lost for me in exams there :-)